# Google Drive Pictures not appearing in Metro Photos app

Tags: windows-8, google-drive

All my photos are stored in my Google Drive, but the Drive photos do not appear in the Metro Photo's app (those placed directly in the My Pictures folder do).

Looking in the indexing settings shows:

[image]

so it appears not to be being indexed.

I've also tried added the Google Drive/Pictures folder to the Pictures Library too, to no avail!

How can I get Google Drive'd pictures to appear in the Photos app?

Answer (score 0):

It *is* related to indexing, and permissions.  The answer suggested here works:

https://superuser.com/a/486715/62742

The Google Drive folder only had permissions for the creating user.  You need to add read permissions for the `SYSTEM` user and then rerun the indexer.  Voila - photos appear in the Metro app!