# Windows 7 search isn't returning any results?

Tags: windows-7, windows, search

I've got a folder full of photos and videos that I'd like to transfer just into a single directory (my camera creates a new folder every time you turn it on for some reason!) and apparently the best way to do this is to search the folder, and then select all of the files.

However, when I try to search within that folder (on my C: drive by the way, not on the camera still) I get no results:

[image]

There are lots of files/folders in there:

[image]

And I get the error with search indexing turned on or off.

I've also followed the steps detailed here: [Windows 7 search does not return results from indexed folders](https://superuser.com/questions/473263/windows-7-search-does-not-return-results-from-indexed-folders) (made sure the folder is included in indexing, ensured the file types are indexed, checked the security permissions on the folder etc)

Any suggestions would be great, thank you!

(update) searching for *.* also returns no results, and there are lots of files (.MOV and .JPG) within the folders

Comment: Are you searching for "`* `"? Your search is looking for a space in filenames... What does "`*.*`" return?

Comment: Your screen dump shows lots of folders, but no files. Since there are only 71 items found altogether, I suspect the folders may be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, searching for *.* also returns no results, and there are lots of files (.MOV and .JPG) within the folders

Comment: You could try use another 'search' program like [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/)